# rails mysql adapter error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. I'm getting the error

> Please install the mysql adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter'

when I specify either `ruby-mysql` or `mysql2` in my `Gemfile`. This has only happened since I've upgraded to Rails 3.1.0-rc1. I'm running OSX 10.6, Ruby 1.9.2.

```
cody$ rails c
/Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/base.rb:2135:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:34:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:177:in `call'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:177:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:177:in `each'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:177:in `load_console'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:115:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:115:in `load_console'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:26:in `start'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is the `gem env` output

```
cody$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin10.7.3]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/cody/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-10
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
   - /Users/cody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
   - http://gems.github.com
```

Comment: I believe I've fixed my problem. I set `  adapter: mysql2` instead of `  adapter: mysql` in database.yml

I apologize for the noise.

Comment: suggest the original poster accept Brad Folkens' answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to enforce the use of mysql2 gem version 0.2.7 and while trying to upgrade my rails 3.0.7 app to 3.1.0.rc1, I also noticed ,that you'll need the following new gems in your Gemfile, too:

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3' # as stated above

# Asset template engines
gem 'json'
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'
# other required things for rails 3.1
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mustang' # this is ONE execjs backend of many, and the only one that worked for me.
```

Tell me if that worked for you.

Comment: any reason for restricting the gem version to '< 0.3' ?

Answer (score 56):

You'll have to change your `config/database.yml` to use the `mysql2` adapter instead of `mysql`.

So replace:

```
adapter: mysql
```

With:

```
adapter: mysql2
```

Comment: A note to anyone using the Amazon RDS add-on on Heroku, you'll need to make this change, and also change the DB URL in the RDS addon to use `mysql2://` instead of `mysql://` otherwise you'll still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by updating the gemfile for my app to identify mysql2 as part of the bundle.

To do this, navigate to the root of your app, run `open gemfile`

Add the line `gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3.7'` directly below the gem line for rails.

While in terminal at the root of your app, run `bundle install`

Run `bundle show mysql2` to verify the bundle worked.  You should be good to go with the adapter now.

My environment is Rails 3.1, MySql 5.5, Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Rails project on windows and moved it to a machine running Fedora. I solved this problem by renaming the "Gemfile.lock" to "old_Gemfile.lock". Of course, you must still specify the adapter as 'mysql2' and include the appropriate gem in your gemfile.