# ActiveRecord.... activerecord-mysql-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is driving me farking insane.

I'm trying to create a simple beginner app utilizing ActiveRecord to do simple database tasks. I'm NOT using rails.

I keep getting the error:

```
RuntimeError: Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (Could not find mysql (~> 2.8.1) amongst [actionmailer-3.1.3, actionpack-3.1.3, activemodel-3.1.3, activerecord-3.1.3, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.1.4, activeresource-3.1.3, activesupport-3.1.3, ansi-1.4.1, arel-2.2.1, bigdecimal-1.1.0, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.21, capistrano-2.9.0, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.1.3, daemons-1.1.4, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-0.12.10, execjs-1.2.9, highline-1.6.8, hike-1.2.1, hpricot-0.8.5, i18n-0.6.0, io-console-0.3, jquery-rails-1.0.19, json-1.6.3, mail-2.3.0, mime-types-1.17.2, minitest-2.5.1, multi_json-1.0.4, net-scp-1.0.4, net-sftp-2.0.5, net-ssh-2.2.1, net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, nokogiri-1.5.0, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.3.5, rack-cache-1.1, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-protection-1.1.4, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.1.3, railties-3.1.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.11, rockhands-0.0.6, sass-3.1.11, sass-rails-3.1.5, shotgun-0.9, sinatra-1.3.1, sprockets-2.0.3, sqlite3-1.3.4, thin-1.3.1, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, turn-0.8.3, tzinfo-0.3.31, uglifier-1.1.0])
```

This gem obviously doesn't exist on rubygems, or this would be easy...

How else am I supposed to do this?

Heres the important part

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql',
  :host     => 'localhost',
  :database => 'test',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => 'password'
)
```

I can see whatever I change :adapter to in the hash is what it inserts into the error 'gem install activerecord-yousuck-adapter'

I've read just about every guide on google I can find...... at my wits end. I thought this would be at least a little easier.... I've spent hours and hours just fixing gem errors. Days in fact, and I have yet to write any actual ruby code. how frustrating.

Comment: Did you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141276/rails-3-1-0-rc1-mysql-adapter-error ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem but try using the `adapter: mysql2`  driver. It's the recommended anyway since it's way faster than the standard `mysql` one.

Do you still get the same issue?

Comment: I downloaded that cause i read that in other places, but it just says can't find activerecord-mysql2-adapter. i dont see how it could though because its called 'mysql2'. can i specify the gem name of the adapter to activerecord?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Do you mean using a different name than the one the gem is identified by?

Comment: well, I changed adapter to "mysql2" and now the error is this: RuntimeError: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`... so how do I tell activerecord to look at a gem called 'mysql2' and not activerecord-mysql2-adapter

Comment: Is the gem installed? You should be able to just do `gem install mysql2`

Comment: yes its installed. i think its looking for it as 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' instead of just 'mysql2'

Comment: finally, this fixed it: sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Answer (score 5):

After hours of fighting with this issue, Tallboy's answer worked for me on OS X:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Unfortunately his answer was hidden in one of the comments above; you have to click the link to expand the comment. I was getting the error message "undefined method 'init' for Mysql:Class"

Answer (score 2):

1. I issued **bundle install** command, which didn't resolve the issue
2. I found the gemfile located in c:\Sites\<>\Gemfile
3. Added **gem 'mysql'** to the file by editing it in notepad++
4. Then checked whether Mysql is avilable in the bundle using  **bundle show mysql**
5. After which when i issued rake db:create , I got specified file could not be found error which is was referring to libmysql.dll
6. You can find the same in your mysql installation or you can download from the link 
   http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/libmysqldll-32-bit-download/
7. Copy that file to the Ruby directory bin folder. In My case I was using rubyinstaller so it was C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin

Voila. That's done.

^Note that the download link might lead to an incorrect library version. In which case, it's best to follow the link given in the message you get right after installing the mysql(2) gem to get the correct library version, otherwise it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem (because we switch from jruby to ruby)

Solved with :

- adapter: mysql2 (in database.yml)
- gem 'mysql2' (in the gemfile)