# rails mysql capistrano DB migrations failed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Now is the time to migrate to mysql from sqlite
I've added

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

to Gemfile and installed it here. The old production with sqlite runs normally. When I switched the `database.yml` in production to mysql and mysql server DBName and Password and committed it via git to the server try to deploy, I get this error:

```
 [out :: server] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: server] Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
 ** [out :: server] 
 ** [out :: server] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
 ** [out :: server] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 9827ms
```

How can I fix it or how can install the gem on the server? If I run `bundle list` I can see that mysql2 is installed. Which module do I have to install?

I get the Error if I try to install: activerecord-mysql-adapter

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter,
activerecord-jdbc-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter, activerecord-odbc-adapter,
activerecord-nulldb-adapter
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this gem activerecord-mysql-adapter? As the error message says try running "gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter"

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141276/rails-mysql-adapter-error

Comment: The Link was the right tipp for us. I've added adapter: mysql2 and it runs. The next step is to optimize the mysql apache2 performance Thanks at all!